# Connect to docker container using IP

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-machine

I'm running the next commands:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v17.06.2-ce   

$ docker-machine ip default
192.168.99.100
```

And I have some docker containers.
Once of the is running `django`, other one `postgres` and a third one elastic search.

When I'm running my `django` container with:

```
# python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

And it is working when I use the site:

```
localhost:8000/
```

But, is not available when I use: `192.168.99.100:8000`
There, I have the browser message:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> 192.168.99.100 refused to connect. Try: Checking the connection

The same happens for the `postgres` and `elasticseach` container.

Why my docker container is not applying the `default docker-machine ip` ?

Comment: please add output of `docker ps`

Comment: In addition to output of `docker ps`, it would help to show either the `docker run` commands or the docker-compose.yml used to launch the containers. I suspect you are not exposing the container ports, and are accessing `localhost:8000` from inside the Django container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have not told Docker to talk to your VM, and that your containers are running on your host machine.

To resolve:

1. Bring down your containers
2. Run `$ eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` which sets the following environment variables:

   ```
   export DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY="1"
   export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://x.x.x.x:2376"
   export DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users/<yourusername>/.docker/machine/machines/default"
   export DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME="default"
   ```

   This tells Docker how to talk to your VM.
3. Spin containers back up

Comment: You right! the `docker-machine` wasn't talking with the docker container. Thanks